# Body content hidden by header navigation section bar - bootstrap - css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am making a new website and am using a template that I like.  Note that I have two "About Us" section exactly the same, that's just filler for now, but you can see what is getting cut off by seeing the image of webpage.

Not sure what I need to do to fix this overlap of body content issue. I tried margin-top padding, fixed positioning, z-index but I am doing something wrong. I have the main web page done already and I do not having any body overlap issues because I'm using a flexslider directly below the top header where my navigation lies.

I have been trying numerous possible fixes from Stack Overflow, but I cannot fix this problem.

Thank you!

[image]

```css
/*

Compass Template
    
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass


http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)

*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Styling 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font: 13px/23px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #777777;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
}

.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons, .main-header .menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#homecontent, #portfolio, #about, #contact, #vinnies, #outreach, #crossroads {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Header Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.top-header {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 1000
  position: fixed
}

.top-header .left-header span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 20px 0 0;
}
.top-header .left-header span i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a {
  color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970;
}
.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-header .logo {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.main-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-header .logo h1 a {
  color: #444444;
}
.main-header .menu {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a.current {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
}
.main-header-shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
  top: 0;
}
.responsive-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1601c;
  margin: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a.current {
  background-color: #444444;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Layout Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.title-section {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.title-section h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title-section span {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #191970;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.widget-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.mainBtn {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.mainBtn:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Specialty Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#portfolio {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #3d3f3f;
}
#portfolio .title-section h2 {
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(227, 114, 46, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner h4 a {
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Home Content Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header .homecontent-description {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;

}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 24px; 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a {
  color: #191970;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: solid; 1px; #191970;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: #9fff80;
  color: #191970;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 About Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#about .progess-bars li .progress {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#about .progess-bars li .progress-bar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #191970;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#about .our-team {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #191970;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content span {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Crossroads Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Outreach Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/




/*------------------------------------------------------
 Crossroads Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Contact Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#contact .contact-form .full-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#contact .contact-form input, #contact .contact-form textarea {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #777777;
}
#contact .contact-form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contact .contact-form input.mainBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}
#contact .map-holder {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
#contact .contact-info {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#contact .contact-info span {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#contact .contact-info span i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.flexslider {
  margin-top: 114px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  color: #444444;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.flex-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
}
.flex-caption h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.flex-caption p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.flex-caption span {
  background: url(../images/slider-dec.png) no-repeat;
  width: 60px;
  height: 9px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------
 Footer Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-footer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
.site-footer p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.site-footer a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.site-footer .go-top {
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-footer .go-top i {
  display: block;
}

/********************************
IPAD LANDSCAPE (1024x768)
********************************/
/********************************
IPAD PORTRAIT (768x1024)
********************************/



@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .main-header {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .service-item, .team-member {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .our-skills {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .flex-caption {
    top: 20%;
  }
  .flex-caption h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flex-caption p {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-header, .right-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 LANDSCAPE (568x320)
********************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .flex-caption {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .contact-form {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  .main-header {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .responsive-menu .menu {
    top: 32px;
  }
}


/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 PORTRAIT (320x568)
********************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI - Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="templatemo">
    <!-- 
    Compass Template
    http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass
    -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 

    <!-- CSS Bootstrap & Custom -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-misc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-main.css">
        
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
            <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="header">
        <div class="site-header">
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="left-header">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>920-892-4913</span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@svdpplymouth.org">info@svdpplymouth.org</a></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>M-F 9AM-7PM SAT 9AM-5PM</span>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="right-header text-right">
                                <ul class="social-icons">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/?q=#/svdpplymouth" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/svdpply/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/svdpplymouth/" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/svdp_ply" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.top-header -->
            <div class="main-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <h1><img src="images/SVDPlogotitle.png"></h1>
                            </div> <!-- /.logo -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="store.html">Vinnies</a></li>
         <li><a href="outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.menu -->
      </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="responsive-menu text-right visible-xs visible-sm">
                        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu fa fa-bars"></a>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="store.html">Vinnies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                <li><a href="crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.menu -->
                    </div> <!-- /.responsive-menu -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.header -->
        </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
    </div> <!-- /#home -->
 
 
    <div id="about" class="section-cotent">
        <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4 class="widget-title">The Society of St. Vincent de Paul</h4>
     <p>Inspired by Gospel values, the Society of St. Vincent de Paul, a Catholic lay organization, leads women and men to join together to grow spiritually by offering person-to-person service to those who are needy and suffering in the tradition of its founder, Blessed Frédéric Ozanam, and patron, St. Vincent de Paul. <br><br>As a reflection of the whole family of God, members, who are known as Vincentians, are drawn from every ethnic and cultural background, age group, and economic level. Vincentians are united in an international society of charity by their spirit of poverty, humility and sharing, which is nourished by prayer and reflection, mutually supportive gatherings and adherence to a basic Rule.<br><br>Organized locally, Vincentians witness God's love by embracing all works of charity and justice. The Society collaborates with other people of good will in relieving need and addressing its causes, making no distinction in those served because, in them, Vincentians see the face of Christ.</p>
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 vincent-video">
     <iframe width="420" height="315"
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zrwez_neJT4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>">
     </iframe>
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
   </div> <!-- /.row --> 
  </div> <!-- /.container top -->
 </div> <!-- /$about -->
 
 
 
    <div id="about" class="section-cotent">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4 class="widget-title">The Society of St. Vincent de Paul</h4>
                    <p>Inspired by Gospel values, the Society of St. Vincent de Paul, a Catholic lay organization, leads women and men to join together to grow spiritually by offering person-to-person service to those who are needy and suffering in the tradition of its founder, Blessed Frédéric Ozanam, and patron, St. Vincent de Paul. <br><br>As a reflection of the whole family of God, members, who are known as Vincentians, are drawn from every ethnic and cultural background, age group, and economic level. Vincentians are united in an international society of charity by their spirit of poverty, humility and sharing, which is nourished by prayer and reflection, mutually supportive gatherings and adherence to a basic Rule.<br><br>Organized locally, Vincentians witness God's love by embracing all works of charity and justice. The Society collaborates with other people of good will in relieving need and addressing its causes, making no distinction in those served because, in them, Vincentians see the face of Christ.</p>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 vincent-video">
     <iframe width="420" height="315"
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zrwez_neJT4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>">
     </iframe>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row --> 
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
 </div> <!-- /$about -->
  
  
 
    <div class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI</p>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="go-top">
                        <a href="#" id="go-top">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                            Back to Top
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.site-footer -->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
     scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.758468,100.567481)
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
              'callback=initialize';
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give following css:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.section-cotent{
  margin-top: 170px;
  }
```

Full code HERE:

```css
/*

Compass Template
    
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass


http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)

*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Styling 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font: 13px/23px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #777777;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
}

.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons, .main-header .menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#homecontent, #portfolio, #about, #contact, #vinnies, #outreach, #crossroads {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Header Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.top-header {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 1000
  position: fixed
}

.top-header .left-header span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 20px 0 0;
}
.top-header .left-header span i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a {
  color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970;
}
.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-header .logo {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.main-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-header .logo h1 a {
  color: #444444;
}
.main-header .menu {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a.current {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
}
.main-header-shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
  top: 0;
}
.responsive-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1601c;
  margin: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a.current {
  background-color: #444444;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Basic Layout Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.title-section {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.title-section h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title-section span {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #191970;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.widget-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.mainBtn {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.mainBtn:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Specialty Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#portfolio {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #3d3f3f;
}
#portfolio .title-section h2 {
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(227, 114, 46, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner h4 a {
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb .overlay .inner span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-thumb:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Home Content Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header .homecontent-description {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;

}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 24px; 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-item .homecontent-header h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a {
  color: #191970;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: solid; 1px; #191970;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
#homecontent .homecontent-description ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: #9fff80;
  color: #191970;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 About Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#about .progess-bars li .progress {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#about .progess-bars li .progress-bar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #191970;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#about .our-team {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img .overlay .social li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
#about .our-team .team-member .member-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #191970;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#about .our-team .team-member .inner-content span {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------
 Crossroads Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Outreach Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/




/*------------------------------------------------------
 Crossroads Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/



/*------------------------------------------------------
 Contact Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
#contact .contact-form .full-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#contact .contact-form input, #contact .contact-form textarea {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #777777;
}
#contact .contact-form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contact .contact-form input.mainBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}
#contact .map-holder {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
#contact .contact-info {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#contact .contact-info span {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#contact .contact-info span i {
  color: #191970;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.flexslider {
  margin-top: 114px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  color: #444444;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.flex-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
}
.flex-caption h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.flex-caption p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.flex-caption span {
  background: url(../images/slider-dec.png) no-repeat;
  width: 60px;
  height: 9px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------
 Footer Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-footer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
.site-footer p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.site-footer a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.site-footer .go-top {
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-footer .go-top i {
  display: block;
}

/********************************
IPAD LANDSCAPE (1024x768)
********************************/
/********************************
IPAD PORTRAIT (768x1024)
********************************/



@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .main-header {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .service-item, .team-member {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .our-skills {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .flex-caption {
    top: 20%;
  }
  .flex-caption h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flex-caption p {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-header, .right-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 LANDSCAPE (568x320)
********************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .flex-caption {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .contact-form {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  .main-header {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .responsive-menu .menu {
    top: 32px;
  }
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.section-cotent{
  margin-top: 170px;
  }

/********************************
IPHONE 4-4S-5 PORTRAIT (320x568)
********************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI - Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="templatemo">
    <!-- 
    Compass Template
    http://www.templatemo.com/tm-454-compass
    -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 

    <!-- CSS Bootstrap & Custom -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-misc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-main.css">
        
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
            <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="header">
        <div class="site-header">
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="left-header">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>920-892-4913</span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@svdpplymouth.org">info@svdpplymouth.org</a></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>M-F 9AM-7PM SAT 9AM-5PM</span>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="right-header text-right">
                                <ul class="social-icons">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/?q=#/svdpplymouth" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/svdpply/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/svdpplymouth/" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/svdp_ply" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.left-header -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.top-header -->
            <div class="main-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <h1><img src="images/SVDPlogotitle.png"></h1>
                            </div> <!-- /.logo -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="store.html">Vinnies</a></li>
         <li><a href="outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.menu -->
      </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="responsive-menu text-right visible-xs visible-sm">
                        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu fa fa-bars"></a>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="store.html">Vinnies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
                                <li><a href="crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.menu -->
                    </div> <!-- /.responsive-menu -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
            </div> <!-- /.header -->
        </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
    </div> <!-- /#home -->
 
 
    <div id="about" class="section-cotent">
        <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4 class="widget-title">The Society of St. Vincent de Paul</h4>
     <p>Inspired by Gospel values, the Society of St. Vincent de Paul, a Catholic lay organization, leads women and men to join together to grow spiritually by offering person-to-person service to those who are needy and suffering in the tradition of its founder, Blessed Frédéric Ozanam, and patron, St. Vincent de Paul. <br><br>As a reflection of the whole family of God, members, who are known as Vincentians, are drawn from every ethnic and cultural background, age group, and economic level. Vincentians are united in an international society of charity by their spirit of poverty, humility and sharing, which is nourished by prayer and reflection, mutually supportive gatherings and adherence to a basic Rule.<br><br>Organized locally, Vincentians witness God's love by embracing all works of charity and justice. The Society collaborates with other people of good will in relieving need and addressing its causes, making no distinction in those served because, in them, Vincentians see the face of Christ.</p>
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 vincent-video">
     <iframe width="420" height="315"
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zrwez_neJT4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>">
     </iframe>
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
   </div> <!-- /.row --> 
  </div> <!-- /.container top -->
 </div> <!-- /$about -->
 
 
 
    <div id="about" class="section-cotent">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4 class="widget-title">The Society of St. Vincent de Paul</h4>
                    <p>Inspired by Gospel values, the Society of St. Vincent de Paul, a Catholic lay organization, leads women and men to join together to grow spiritually by offering person-to-person service to those who are needy and suffering in the tradition of its founder, Blessed Frédéric Ozanam, and patron, St. Vincent de Paul. <br><br>As a reflection of the whole family of God, members, who are known as Vincentians, are drawn from every ethnic and cultural background, age group, and economic level. Vincentians are united in an international society of charity by their spirit of poverty, humility and sharing, which is nourished by prayer and reflection, mutually supportive gatherings and adherence to a basic Rule.<br><br>Organized locally, Vincentians witness God's love by embracing all works of charity and justice. The Society collaborates with other people of good will in relieving need and addressing its causes, making no distinction in those served because, in them, Vincentians see the face of Christ.</p>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 vincent-video">
     <iframe width="420" height="315"
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zrwez_neJT4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>">
     </iframe>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row --> 
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
 </div> <!-- /$about -->
  
  
 
    <div class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Society of St. Vincent de Paul Plymouth WI</p>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="go-top">
                        <a href="#" id="go-top">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                            Back to Top
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.site-footer -->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
     scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.758468,100.567481)
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
              'callback=initialize';
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you !! This worked. There's just one thing going on, yet. When I scroll down the page now, you can see the body content scrolls over the top of the fixed logo/nav header. I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: @hugsnat I am not sure understood what you are trying to say.

Comment: I'm going to attach a screen shot of what is happening on the web page. When I scroll further down the web page content, the content scrolls over the top of the fixed header where my logo and nav is located.

Comment: I'm not allowed to attach a screenshot of what's happening. And this is an offline website so I cannot provide a link :(

Comment: @hugsnat upload screenshot here and give link of that image.

Comment: I found this reference: https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/   Because this is what is happening. But I'm not sure if this will work. I have a few jump to links in my "about-section-content" now. Just links to jump to the h4 topics that are on my page now.

Comment: I added this js and when i click on an anchor link it takes me to the anchored h4 location perfectly. The anchored link doesn't headbutt the browser window anymore. It locates it below my header (site header). But body content does not slip under the header...it appears above it like it's floating above my header area. I do not know what to do. The js script I added on the page is:  
<script>
    var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -140) };
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
    function load() { if (window.location.hash) shiftWindow(); } </script>

Comment: I think it's working now. I will upload changes that were made tomorrow. I'm going to publish so I can give a link for viewing too. I really appreciate your help and guidance!!!

Comment: @hugsnat You can accept it as answer. If it helps to solve your issue. By clicking on right symbol

Comment: How do I accept your answer on here? I would like to.

Comment: @hugsnat just click on Right symbol below my vote count. (left top of my answer) http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVOyc.png